# What to call mother-in-law after divorce?

Tags: kinship-terms

After my divorce, do I still call my mother-in-law "mother"? We are not on that good terms at the moment. To her I am the enemy, even though I did not file for divorce. She would still be the grandma of my children and I don't want to complicate things for my children.

Comment: Call her by her name.

Comment: Usually it's "that witch", but there's nothing wrong with "ex-mother-in-law".  (For the kids pick a "pet" name such as "Grammie".)

Comment: Depending on your mother-in-law, you might be better off not calling her at all. ;-)

Comment: *My kids' Grandma*

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to her as your *ex-mother-in-law*, as in [this e-card](http://www.someecards.com/usercards/viewcard/MjAxMi1iMDUxZThmMDRkMDE3Njhl) and many other examples:

> Dear ex-mother-in-law,
>   You were never too fond of me, but you'll come to miss me. I was probably your last chance to get rid of your overgrown manchild aka "son".

As for how you choose to address her to her face, that's a matter more for social advice columnists than for this forum. You could continue with "mother", or as frequently done in English (which is rather loose and informal with titles anyway), just address her by first name.